# Efficient/Scalable way to store and retrieve UUID as binary on MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, uuid, knex.js

I am using UUID as the PK (`BINARY(16)`) for the tables on MySQL. Which option is better to convert the binary to/from UUID string?

The first option is using MySQL built-in functions `UUID_TO_BIN` and `BIN_TO_UUID`. This is the easiest to handle UUID/binary convert. But I guess it could cause performance problems at some point.

The second option is to run the convert on the application layer (Node.js). This way, the performance will not be a big problem since web servers are horizontally scalable. However, the code could get a bit messy.

From my research, Postgres handles UUID very well. Does MySQL perform well as same as Postgres and no need to worry about performance?

---

My code for each method is something like below.

### MySQL

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable SET id = UUID_TO_BIN("709fe2ce-be43-11ea-a4e2-784f439a6382", 1);

SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(id, 1) as id FROM mytable WHERE id = UUID_TO_BIN("709fe2ce-be43-11ea-a4e2-784f439a6382", 1);
```

### Application (Node.js with knex)

```js
async function add(data: DataType): Promise<void> {
  await knex("mytable").insert({
    ...data,
    id: toBinaryUUID(data.uuid),
  });
}

async function find(uuid: string): Promise<DataType | undefined> {
  const query = knex
    .select("id")
    .from("mytable")
    .where("id", toBinaryUUID(uuid));

  const record = await query.first();

  if (record) {
    record.id = fromBinaryUUID(record.id);
  }

  return record;
}
```

(I use [odo-network/binary-uuid](https://github.com/odo-network/binary-uuid) as the converting functions.)

```js
function fromBinaryUUID(buf: Buffer): string {
  return [
    buf.toString("hex", 4, 8),
    buf.toString("hex", 2, 4),
    buf.toString("hex", 0, 2),
    buf.toString("hex", 8, 10),
    buf.toString("hex", 10, 16),
  ].join("-");
}

function toBinaryUUID(uuid: string): Buffer {
  const buf = Buffer.from(uuid.replace(/-/g, ""), "hex");
  return Buffer.concat([
    buf.slice(6, 8),
    buf.slice(4, 6),
    buf.slice(0, 4),
    buf.slice(8, 16),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL 8, those functions should be used.

- 16 bytes is better than 36 characters (space, etc)
- The functions rearrange the bits so that uuids that were created about the same time are "close" to each other in the table.  This provides a temporal locality of reference, thereby speeding up a significant class of queries.
- Hand-rolled conversion routines could, but probably don't, rearrange the bits.
- Only Type 1 uuids benefit from the rearrangement, but that is the type that MySQL uses.
- If your uuids come from elsewhere, the rearrangement does not hurt, but may not help.
- If you are not using MySQL 8.0, those routines are not built-in, but can be found in the link below.
- With MySQL 8.0, include the swap_flag (second argument) as `1`.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think calling `BIN_TO_UUID` has an overhead and affects performance?

Comment: @senta - Any function call, in itself, has low overhead.  UUIDs, in a larger table, inherently lead to high overhead unless the bits are rearranged.  See my blog.  See also the term "sargeable", which does not apply in your examples.

Comment: I went through your blog post. I think now I have a bit comprehended understanding of UUID. Thanks a lot for the information on SO and your blog.